# Not able to use oData query options

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have an ASP.NET Web API project. I'm trying to pass some query options to my API controller like so:

```
http://localhost:61736/api/Enquiries?
callback=callback&$top=30&$skip=30&orderby=EnquiryId
&$inlinecount=allpages&_=1346164698393
```

But I get the following:

`The query parameter '$inlinecount' is not supported.`

I also get the same when I try to use `$callback`, `$format`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx I should be able to use them?

Comment: Now it is supported http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ASP.NET Web API provides only **limited** support for OData as [documented in this blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) I didn't see the query parameters you mention in that list.

Comment: I guess you could you create an ApiController that would be a proxy to a regular OData based service. The OData service would actually perform the query and your controller would just return responses.

Answer (score 2):

In current version, web api only supports $filter, $orderby, $top and $skip. You can override QueryableAttribute to add more support on OData protocol. A checkin after public nuget release has made ValidateQuery method virtual so that you can override it to bypass the validation. Please try our nightly build at http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/.

You can also use ODataQueryOptions. The following code is equivalent to [Queryable] attribute, except that it won't throw exception when it sees unsupported options.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Get(ODataQueryOptions options) 
{
    return options.ApplyTo(_db.Products as IQueryable) as IEnumerable<Product>; 
}
```

You can get $inlinecount by ODataQueryOptions.RawValues.InlineCount.
For detail of OData query support, please see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/21/web-api-queryable-current-support-and-tentative-roadmap.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Support for $inlinecount was checked into the project on 12/6/2012, presumably the next release will contain this support. you can download the latest source or pick up a nightly build:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/ed65e90e83c8

```
Revision: ed65e90e83c8f9391b4f4806d305c83f55d28ff6
Author: youssefm < youssefm@microsoft.com >
Date: 12/6/2012 1:51:44 PM
Message:
[OData] Add support for the $inlinecount query option
```

I believe nightly packages are pushed to http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/ but I have not verified myself.

Comment: The current nightly build doesn't complain about $inlinecount, but it also doesn't provide a properly formatted response which includes count (e.g. no change in behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using KendoUI by any chance [this post](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-10-25/using_kendo_ui_with_mvc4_webapi_odata_and_ef.aspx) explains how to disable some of the options such as $callback by switching to JSON instead of JSONP.

Comment: Kendo now supports ODATA V4 there is no longer any need for tweaks to make it work.

You can change the data set type from type: 'odata' to type: 'odata-v4'

Comment: thanks @choco but I gave up on oData long ago - was too much of a mess